# What to set return value for function that normally returns matrix but could fail a conditional

Tags: r, function

I have a function that is supposed to return a matrix for further functions to use. I have it reading in a file and doing calculations, but I need the main function to skip to the next file if the current one does not meet the correct formatting. This is how basically how I have it now:

```
for (file in list.files(directory)) {
    for (i in 1:length(var)) { 
        matrix <- foo('someFile.txt',var[i])     # returns matrix under normal conditions
        if (typeof(matrix)) == "logical") {      # check if foo returns FALSE
            warning(paste0('File ',file, ' is not formatted correctly'))
            break                                # skip to next file if so
        }
        ...
    }
}

foo <- function(input,seq)
    data <- readLines(input)
    if (!data[1] %in% c("first","line","values")) {
        return(FALSE)
    }
    ...
    return(data)
}
```

But testing the class `matrix` returns seems clunky and poor technique. Sorry I don't know how to phrase the question better.

Comment: Why do you think it's clunky and bad form?

Comment: What is the desired outcome? A better way to check out if it is a matrix? Because a simple `is.matrix` could do the job.

Comment: It just seemed to me there was a better approach then the naive one I took in checking what type the return value was. If this looks fine, I'll keep it.